# Есть массив 10 на 10, нужно посчитать суму квадратов элементов каждого столбца и отсортировать эти сумы по убыванию методом Шелла

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть массив 10 на 10, нужно посчитать суму квадратов элементов каждого столбца и отсортировать эти сумы по убыванию методом Шелла
Вот пример кода:

```
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
    const size_t Rows = 10;
    const size_t Cols = 10;
    int a[Rows][Cols] = 
    { 
        {  0,  1,  2,  3, },
        {  4,  5,  6,  7, },
        {  8,  9, 10, 11, },
    };      

    long long int sum[Cols];

    for ( size_t col = 0; col < Cols; col++ )
    {
        sum[col] = 0;

        for ( size_t row = 0; row < Rows; row++ )
        {
            sum[col] += a[row][col];
        }
    }

    for ( size_t row= 0; row < Rows; row++ )
    {
        for ( size_t col = 0; col < Cols; col++ )
        {
            std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << a[row][col] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( long long int x : sum ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Вам нужно найти **сумму квадратов элементов** каждого столбца, а почему-то пишите:

   ```
   sum[col] += a[row][col];
   ```

   То есть вы находите просто сумму столбца, а нужно **сумму квадратов**:

   ```
   sum[col] += a[row][col] * (long long int)a[row][col];
   ```
2. Насчет сортировки Шелла. Вы даже на начали её писать, хотя в интернете куча информации (ну или целого кода), так что тут я помогу лишь ссылками на источники.

   [Идея алгоритма](https://forkettle.ru/vidioteka/programmirovanie-i-set/algoritmy-i-struktury-dannykh/108-sortirovka-i-poisk-dlya-chajnikov/1008-sortirovka-shella) (так же там есть и реализация на разных языках) и [реализация алгоритма](https://vscode.ru/prog-lessons/sortirovka-shella.html)

   Чтобы мой ответ не попадал под удаление по причине "Это ответ-ссылка (но не спам)", приведу реализацию алгоритма из последнего источника:

   ```
   void ShellSort(int n, int mass[])
   {
       int i, j, step;
       int tmp;
       for (step = n / 2; step > 0; step /= 2)
           for (i = step; i < n; i++)
           {
               tmp = mass[i];
               for (j = i; j >= step; j -= step)
               {
                   if (tmp < mass[j - step])
                       mass[j] = mass[j - step];
                   else
                       break;
               }
               mass[j] = tmp;
           }
   }
   ```

   Только нужно учитывать, что массив у вас типа `long long int`, а в реализации `int`